# StringVar on tkinter Entry works. StringVar on ttk.Entry fails

Tags: tkinter

The following code packs two tkinter Entry fields into the root tk window. The displayed text is set via a `StringVar`. The functions that create the two fields are identical except that one creates a `tkinter.Entry` object and the other creates a `tkinter.ttk.Entry` object.

According to Shipman's text both the `tkinter.Entry` and `tkinter.ttk.Entry` have `textvariable` options. They both refer to the same `.get()` and `.set()` method for the `StringVar`. I have been unable to find anything which suggests that the `ttk.Entry` class requires separate treatment.

Why does `ttk.Entry` fail to show the text?

[image]

(Python 3.5.1 on MS Windows 7)

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.ttk


def label_2(root):
    label = tkinter.ttk.Entry(root)
    var_text = tkinter.StringVar(name='StringVar 2')
    label.config(textvariable=var_text)
    var_text.set('variable label 2')
    root.update_idletasks()  # Shipman recommended precaution has no effect here
    print(var_text, var_text.get(), label.get())
    label.pack()


def label_3(root):
    label = tkinter.Entry(root)
    var_text = tkinter.StringVar(name='StringVar 3')
    label.config(textvariable=var_text)
    var_text.set('variable label 3')
    root.update_idletasks()  # Shipman recommended precaution has no effect here
    print(var_text, var_text.get(), label.get())
    label.pack()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    label_2(root)
    label_3(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to differences in implementation, the ttk version of the widget is susceptible to having the variable be garbage-collected. If you keep a persistent reference to the variable your code will work. For example, if you add `global var_text` inside `label_2`, it will work.

Personally I see no value in using a `StringVar` with `Entry` widgets, unless you are relying on some of the special features of the class such as variable traces, or connecting more than one widget to the same variable.

Note: calling `update_idletasks` in these functions is completely pointless. This is doubly true since you're calling it before calling `pack`. That is, until you call `pack` or `grid` or `place`, no task will be added to the idle queue for this particular widget. `update_idletask` will only affect widgets that have been added to the screen but not drawn yet.

And while you think it has no side effect, it actually does. Calling `update_idletasks` refreshes *all* idle tasks, not just the ones created in this function. That being said, it's harmless because all it does is cause a screen refresh, which will happen anyway as soon as mainloop is called.

Comment: I wonder how many others have fallen into the trap of thinking that the StringVar object becomes part of the parent widget and thus would have its reference count increased.

Answer (score 0):

I use `var_text.trace_add('write', lambda val, index, value: var_text.get())` to keep the reference. Between clases works for me.